# Position different text elements in an <option>

Tags: html, forms

I have a  form input in witch I display these informations :
[what is currently displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9T0fA.png)

Each line corresponds to one employee, "Bla bla" is his/her name and first name, "Bordeaux" is the city where he/she works in, and "Agent d'entretien" is his/her job.
What I would like to do is to divide the select area into 3 columns to display them, I've tried with divs and classes but any tag inside an option seems to be forbidden.

Could somebody help me out? Thanks!

Comment: can you please post your code?

Comment: It doesn't seem, it's really forbidden)

Comment: You can pre-format strings to look like three columns or you can mock up desired behavior with divs

Answer (score 0):

You can't style an `option` tag because its is not rendered by html, but rendered by the OS. Hence it can't be styled by CSS. There plugins you can use that style html elements that look like `SELECT` tag with `options` but in reality they are actually regular HTML elements that are styled to look like dropdowns.

Comment: So I guess I'll have to make a homemade table?

Comment: you can just style divs to look like one. Or search online for custom solutions